# Dependency injection vs assembly dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Say, that I have the following project structure:

```
Application <-> BusinessLogic <-> DataAccessLayer
```

I've prepared all types to use poor-man's-dependency-injection and now I want to introduce the real one using Unity. But I'm struggling on where to put the dependency container and its configuration (i suppose I'll configure it from code).

- **DataAccessLayer** needs to register Context (EF)
- **BusinessLogic** needs to register data repositories (which use context)
- **Application** needs to register services (which use repositories)

For now, the only assembly, which uses the container to actually instantiate classes will be the Application. So I have the following dependency diagram:

- **DI** uses **DataAccessLayer**
- **DI** uses **BusinessLogic**
- **DI** uses **Application**
- **Application** uses **DI**

I have circular reference here, so it seems legit to put **DI** inside **Application**. But then I'd have to reference **DataAccessLayer** and that's a dependency I don't want to create. How should I resolve this problem?

Comment: "DI" should not be dependent on any of this. It's up to the client (`Application` in your case) to register dependencies *using* the DI.

Comment: @haim770 By "DI uses *" I mean: "Someone, who registers types from * must have access to it". If I register types from `Application`, I'd have to create a dependency to `DataAccessLayer`, but I don't want to do that (if possible, at least).

Comment: Even if you're delegating the registration to the DI project, you don't really gain anything as eventually the application *is* dependent on those assemblies and they *will* be referenced. Perhaps what you're actually after is dynamic registration using Assembly Scanning (http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: @Spook I have no idea why  you face with a problem like circular reference?do you use service locator pattern in your layers? using service locator pattern is not correct  way when you use a DI container

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a DI container, then you should only use it in the Application itself, not in your other class libraries (e.g. BusinessLogic and DataAccessLayer). The place in the Application where you compose your object graph is called the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Quoting for that article:

> Only applications should have Composition Roots. Libraries and frameworks shouldn't.

Since you have already prepared your classes to enable poor man DI (now called [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/)), you should be fine. DI is now enabled in your libraries (Please note that DI and DI containers are different things).

Your application now can wire everything together from all the class libraries, even if that means that your application project will need to reference all the other class libraries.

**In my opinion**, you would be better off without a DI container (even in the application layer), see [this article](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex.html) for a reason why.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the DL layer create a method to register its components.
2. In the BL layer do the same but also call the DL method.
3. In the A layer do the same but also call the BL method.

That way the relatively upper layer is shielded from the lower layers and everything is properly registered. To the A layer it is an implementation detail that the DL even exists. It only knows about the BL layer.