# DI container for 2 layers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, architecture

I'm trying to design WebApi application with using IoC like Ninject. I have the following layers(3 projects):

- Domain(Repository) layer
- Service
- Web API application core

The Repository layer has interface `IRepository<T>` and a few implementations of it. And in the Service also exists interface `IService<T>` with a two different implementations.

Could you please advise me should I use DI container (Ninject) in WebApi project to bind `IService<T>` and `ServiceConcrete<T>` and DI container in the Service project to bind `IRepository<T>` and `RepositoryConcrete<T>`?

Or maybe should I use only one DI in WebAppi project?

Comment: You should use only one DI container in the WebAPI project.

Comment: Thank you @YacoubMassad. How should I configure proper repository for Service layer? Can you help me or more explain?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062860/dependency-injection-vs-assembly-dependencies

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899181/di-and-repository-pattern

Comment: In summary, only applications (not class libraries) should use a DI container. The place where you do that is called the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)

Comment: Do I sense it correctly that you might have some sort of anomaly in your setup described? Domain _should not_ be aware of repository implementations at all as it is an _infrastructure_ concern.

Comment: @kayess Could you please explain why do you think so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A practical way I have found to set up Ninject modules can be found below.

#### Overview

1. Create an assembly called `DependencyResolution`
2. Create the Ninject modules (that you will utilize in your WebAPI project)
3. Have only this `DependencyResolution` and your Domain projects referenced in your WebAPI project
4. Initalize/register your modules in `NinjectWebCommon.cs`

#### Details

1. Should be easy as [create a project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173077%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), add Ninject as reference from NuGet for instance.
2. Add new class file(s) to this project named after the modules you want to create like: `ServiceModule.cs`, `RepositoryModule.cs`, etc.
   Create your [Ninject module(s)](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel). For detailed instructions on this you can refer my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776848/using-nininject-mvc-with-class-librarys/33778127#33778127) on this.
3. In your WebAPI project, you add reference to this just created `DependencyResolution` project and your Domain project.
4. Initializing/registering your just created module(s) in the WebAPI project's `NinjectWebCommon.cs` as:

   ```
   private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
   {
       var modules = new List<INinjectModule>
       {
           new ServiceModule(),
           new RepositoryModule()
       };

       kernel.Load(modules);
   }
   ```

---

I will also try to address another concern that is *loosely* related to your question. I think your current layering setup would need a bit to be changed.

The basic and probably my biggest problem with your layers are that **you mix up and therefore tightly couple the Domain and Repository which is clearly an infrastructural concern**.

I would suggest to re-architect your layers as:

- Domain
- Services
- Infrastructure (Repository implementations could go here for instance)
- Dependency Resolution
- WebAPI

Do not forget that your Domain layer should **not** have any idea about *infrastructural* details like Repository, else you are going to tightly couple your domain with unneeded implementation details.

**EDIT:** From the comments I see that you have some concerns about where to place and how to name things which is [obviously](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) one of the hardest things in programming.

So my thoughts on clearing this confusion up are:

*Layer*: is a logical separation or collection point of classes, methods, etc. that those belong together.

Each layer can consists of multiple projects or assemblies. So if you want to categorize your projects into layers, you could create [directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c6c756s6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your solution named about your layers and place the individual projects inside these directories. It's really just a matter of taste in the mouth, take it just as a tip.

#### Example structure

1. Solution root
2. Core directory

   - Domain assembly: the root of you domain where you have your business or domain entities AND the all the interfaces that your domain is using.
   - Domain services assembly (just could be in Domain assembly as well)
3. Services directory

   - Application services assembly: for example an example this assembly houses services or facades that spans operations accross multiple domain entities or aggregates, etc.)
4. Infrastructure directory

   - Repository assembly: this is where you have the implementations of your EF repositories
   - Custom logging/email/whatever else assemblies or implementations that doesn't belong to the domain.
   - DependencyResolution assembly: this is the place of your NInject modules and all IOC container related wirings.
5. UI directory

   - WebAPI assembly
   - Asp.Net MVC assembly

#### Summary

The Dependency Resolution project has references to any needed assemblies (Domain for interfaces, Services/Infrastructure for their implementations) and wire them altogether for later use.

The WebAPI project would only need to have reference added Domain and Dependency Resolution so then you could just ask for your interfaces in your WebAPI methods/functions public constructor and Ninject will do the dirty job for you behind the scenes.

Please don't forget that this is just an easy quick 'n dirty architecture suggestion of mine, without knowing your **exact** requirements and use cases.

Comment: Many thanks @kayess. This is a very good answer. I'm going to follow your instructions and advice. My first question for now is: Will it be correct to name the project "Core" but not "Infrastructure"?

Comment: @DadisX Your welcome! No, I don't recommend name it as "Core", just call your domain project as "Domain" and "Infrastructure" as is because you place there all infrastructural concern implementation which does not belong to Domain. I tend to call Core which is the application core that might include the Domain, Domain Services for instance.

Comment: Thanks again. Should I have all business logic in the Infrastructure layer?

Comment: Nope, never. Business logic is something that's more or less closely related to your domain. Though it's an implementation detail (which you haven't showed in your quest, which is also good because then it would became _too broad_) and therefore it's kinda risky to give a fine answer, but I would say if you use aenemic models you could put business logic into services (this approach is against a lot of good OOP principles), if you follow a somewhat DDD-ish approach you should encapsulate all business logic into the domain entitites itself. .....

Comment: ..... But ff you have more questions about this very broad subject please fire up a new question and have more fine answers from fellow SO contributors. :)

Comment: Sorry but I have the last question. I have the implementations of repository that containt IDbSet<T> from EF. Should I add references to EF in Infrastructure too? Or should I use EF only in Infrastructure  layer? Thank you in advance @kayess

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you're having troubles configuring your Repository layer because your config code is in your application layer, which probably only references your service layer (which in turn references your repository layer). What I've done in order to get around this is first create your configurations in modules (these can live on any layer, but you must reference Ninject)

For your repo layer:

```
public class RepoNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IMyRepo>().To<MyRepo>();
    }
}
```

create a similar Module in your service layer:

```
public class ServiceNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IMyService>().To<MyServce>();
    }
}
```

Then, in your application layer, you can load the modules dynamically (this is what `NinjectWebCommon.cs` looks like):

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
}
```

More info on modules:  https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel